# Use Flex DateField component in Flash CS6

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

I'm trying to use the [Flex DateField](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/DateField.html) component in Flash CS6. I understand flex swc files which come packaged with Flash by default are not the full packages, so I downloaded the flex SDK.

I linked core.swc and mx.swc from the SDK in "Actionscript Settings" in my project. I can now refer to the DateField component, but when I try to add it to the stage, i get the following error:

```
1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: [mx.core]::IIMESupport
1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: [mx.managers]::IFocusManagerComponent
```

I'm adding it in the following way:

```
import mx.controls.DateField;
var df:DateField = new DateField();
addChild(df);
```

I need a date picker component which allows me to disable certain date ranges like before today and after a year and this appears to be the only component that will reliably allow me to do that.

I don't have access to FlashBuilder and FlashDevelop, only Flash Professional CS6. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: addChild which component is method? Peraphs you write  this.addChild(df)?

Comment: Same message, I think `addChild()` defaults to `this.addChild()`

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to use Flex components "as is" in Flash CS6 produced swf at least because the swf document class must be the flex `Application`.

Flex produced swfs (by mxmlc) also contains some additional logic like loading process with run-time-shared libraries loading and so. And flex is not only these two swc that you linked, if you check flex-config.xml you will find more that 10 different swc with some services, themes, utils and more.

But it should be possible to load flex swf inside CS6 swf with a `Loader`.

Comment: Thanks, loading an swf won't help, I need to use the date picker component natively inside flash cs6. All my research on the net seems to suggest that flex is fundamentally different from flash and it's not possible to (easily) merge them :(

Comment: No, Flex builds up on a specific live cycle which is implemented by all components and Flash does not about it. And you don't want to load a Flex SWF for just one component. You should implement your own or find a Flash compatible solution.